# Android ListView and Keyboard

Tags: android, listview

I have created a custom ListView with custom rows. They work just fine when using the touchscreen; however, when I attempt to click on the items in the row with the keyboard D-Pad nothing happens. By that I mean my OnClickListener is not called. Does anyone know of any good references or tutorials on how to add keyboard support for new custom rows in a ListView?

Comment: Custom rows basically works with D-Pad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `setOnItemClickListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

**Edit**
Use an attribute like  on your list item

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Hmm I have that registered as well and it does not run. I think since my row has a checkbox in it the onItemClickListener will never be executed. Do I maybe need to set my CheckBox as not focusable or not clickable?

Comment: Okay this got me going in the right direction. When I set android:focusable="false" then my onItemClickListener was executed on item clicks. At that point I perform a view.performClick() within my onItemClickListener which will give the rows On Click handler a chance to run if it exists. This allows my rows handler to be run as I had originally intended.